# Save json string into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to save a json string into an sql column. What datatype do I need?

```
Varchar(max), xml, text, virbinary(max)
```

In all of them I have the same size 8000bytes

Comment: You can store as text. i.e NVARCHAR. The following link might be helpful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/store-json-documents-in-sql-tables?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Sorry but you didn't send a link. Isn't recommended to go with xml datatype? Also isn't better to use varchar(max) instead of nvarchar(max) ? Cause varchar(max) can save more characters than nvarchar(max)

Comment: Hi what is your sql server version ? If it’s greater than 2016 you can use JSON type https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I tag that it is 2008-r2. I think that things are moved with sql server 2016

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Is xml avoided for this job? Also the thing is that i made some questions which are not answered in link above

Answer (score 1):

Hidden in the link provided above are the details for [varchar()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  If you specify a value [1-8000] then that is the longest data value you can store.  However, where you were mistaken is if you specify varchar(max).  When using max, a single field can have up to 2GB (2^31-1 bytes) of data in it. 
It's important if you're using any non-western languages (arabic, etc) use nvarchar instead.

Edit: varchar(max) isn't wrong, it is up to 2gb, not the 8,000 you mentioned above.

Comment: Why it's mistake to specify specify varchar(max) ? Varchar(max) isn't 8000?

Comment: varchar(max) isn't wrong, but it is up to 2gb, not the 8,000 chars you mentioned above.